# Write to a specific folder in an S3 bucket using boto3 python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

**The question**

I have a file that I would like to write to a specific folder within my S3 bucket lets call the bucket `bucket` and the folder `folderInBucket`

I am using the boto3 library to achieve and have the following function:

**What I have done**

```py
def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name = None):
    
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name
    s3 = b3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3.upload_file(file_name, bucket, Key='bulk_movies.json')
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    print('Success!')
    return True

upload_file('./s3/bulk_movies.json', 'bucket')
```

I have also tried when calling the function using `bucket/folderInBucket` as the second parameter but this produces an error in the code (sort of as expected actually)

**Gaps in understanding**

This function was more or less ripped from the boto3 documentation. The docs don't really specify how to write into a specific folder within our S3 bucket. I know for sure the file itself is able to write fine into the bucket's main directory because the code outlined above works without issue.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but I would recommend checking out `fsspec`: https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest.  See here for example: https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html?highlight=s3%3A%2F%2F#remote-write-caching

Comment: Could you provide the error you're getting?

Comment: you are passing `Key` as just `bulk_movies.json` - there is your problem. I suggest adding `Key` as a configurable param to the function. Try what happens if you pass 
 in `Key='path/to/bulk_movies.json'`

Comment: also, probably related, you're assigning `object_name` but not using it anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by modifying your function and the call a bit to include the object_name as the absolute path to the file on the bucket.

> ```
> import boto3 as b3
>
> def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name):
>     if object_name is None:
>         object_name = file_name
>     s3 = b3.client('s3')
>     try:
>         response = s3.upload_file(file_name, bucket, Key=object_name)
>     except ClientError as e:
>         print(e)
>         return False
>     print('Success!')
>     return True
>
> upload_file('bulk_movies.json', '<bucket-name>', 'folderInBucket/bulk_movies.json')
> ```

Please share the error if you're still running into one. As far as the file upload is concerned, it should work with what you have already done.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is "blob storage" and as such the concept of a "folder" doesn't really exist.  When uploading a file you just provide the complete prefix to the destination string.

Here's an example:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
folder_name = 'folder_name'
s3.meta.client.upload_file('helloworld.txt', 'bucketname', folder_name + '/helloworld.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** such thing - "folder" is s3.
What do you consider as "folder" is part of the file name.

URL example: *s3://mybucket/folder1/folder2/file.txt*

In the example above the file name is 'folder1/folder2/file.txt'

Comment: More common terminology is that `folder1/folder2/file.txt` is an object key (rather than filename), and `folder1/folder2/` is an object key prefix.

Answer (score 0):

buckets are not folders, but they act like folders.  you store objects in a s3 bucket. An object has a key.   The file is uploaded by default with private permissions.  you can set the acl to public-read allowing everyone in the world to see the file.

```
s3.upload_file(
    Bucket='gid-requests',
    Filename='bulk_movies.json',
    Key='folderInBucket/bulk_movies.json',
    ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'})
```